# How can I insert into the table using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am stuck in this condition unable to insert into the table tbl_customer its giving error :

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   The statement has been terminated.

here is my table structure:

```
create table tbl_customer(

id int identity primary key,
cust_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
filecode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
cust_mobile int,
cust_cnic varchar(50) NOT NULL,
cust_phone int,
cust_address varchar(200)

)
```

and here is the code i use to insert:

```
insert into tbl_customer values('Jonah Gordian','LHR001',03451119182,'11-22112-122',1212121212,'abc street 12')
```

and I used this code in c# to try inserting:

```
connclass.insert("insert into tbl_customer(cust_name,filecode,cust_mobile,cust_cnic,cust_phone,cust_address) VALUES('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfilecode.Text + "','" + int.Parse(txtmob.Text) + "','" + txtcnic.Text + "','" + int.Parse(txtphone.Text) + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "')");
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Why are you trying to insert INT values as varchar?

Comment: Your `cust_mobile` and `cust_phone` will be the issue `INT` doesn't start with `0` *(`03451119182`)* plus is too big to fit in an `INT` data type. Should be using `VARCHAR` for phone numbers anyway.

Comment: Do not create a phone number as an integer. It should be varchar. You are not going to use it in math operations.

Comment: connclass.insert("insert into tbl_customer(cust_name,filecode,cust_mobile,cust_cnic,cust_phone,cust_address) VALUES('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfilecode.Text + "','" + txtmob.Text + "','" + txtcnic.Text + "','" + txtphone.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "')");

Comment: It is wrong and open to SQL injection attack. You shouldn't use int or bigint or any other numerics. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table tbl_customer(
id int identity primary key,
cust_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
filecode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
cust_mobile varchar(20),
cust_cnic varchar(50) NOT NULL,
cust_phone varchar(20),
cust_address varchar(200)
)


insert into tbl_customer 
 (cust_name, filecode, cust_mobile, cust_cnic, cust_phone, cust_address )
 values
 ('Jonah Gordian','LHR001','03451119182','11-22112-122','1212121212','abc street 12');
```

And also C# code is open to SQL injection attack, use parameters instead. ie:

```
string sql = @"insert into tbl_customer 
    (cust_name,filecode,cust_mobile,cust_cnic,cust_phone,cust_address) 
    VALUES
    (@cust_name,@filecode,@cust_mobile,@cust_cnic,@cust_phone,@cust_address)";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;database=yourDbName;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
{
  var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_name", txtname.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filecode", txtfilecode.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_mobile", txtmob.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_cnic", txtcnic.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_phone", txtphone.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_address", txtaddress.Text);

  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. for great help

Comment: You are welcome, I didn't add that you should use varchar for phones here but it was in the comments above. On a better design you might want to separate phone into pieces like country, area codes, extension or even to an xml datatype for multiple phone numbers. But in general and for simple phone numbers you can use a plain varchar like this (and users would also be happy they could enter numbers like 444 0 YES :)

Comment: still the same error Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: I didn't count the lengths of the strings. Just check your string lengths against your varchar widths. You might need to use Trim() on your txtName.Text, txtfilecode.Text ...

Comment: According to view yes, you didn't. Add Trim to all those Text's. ie: txtname.Text.Trim(). There might be whitespace offending. You can set a break point at var cmd = ... and check the values lengths. Or you could use profiler to grab exact SQL command sent to SQL server (if you are using SQLExpress which doesn't have profiler, then you can download and use Express Profiler).

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_customer (
    id INT identity PRIMARY KEY
    ,cust_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,filecode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,cust_mobile BIGINT --or Varchar(20)
    ,cust_cnic VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,cust_phone INT
    ,cust_address VARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT INTO tbl_customer
VALUES (
    'Jonah Gordian'
    ,'LHR001'
    ,03451119182
    ,'11-22112-122'
    ,1212121212
    ,'abc street 12'
    )
```

You have exceeded the int datatype limit. Change the datatype from int to either bigint or Varchar to resolve the issue.

Note: If you need leading Zeros then you can choose Varchar otherwise you can make use of BigInt.

Comment: Personally I'd store phone numbers as `VARCHAR` not `BIGINT`.

Comment: @Lankymart: It is based on how we store the data. At the safer side we can choose Varchar because it accepts leading zeros / '-' to separate Country/ISD Code from phone numbers. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: connclass.insert("insert into tbl_customer(cust_name,filecode,cust_mobile,cust_cnic,cust_phone,cust_address) VALUES('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfilecode.Text + "','" + txtmob.Text + "','" + txtcnic.Text + "','" + txtphone.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "')");

Comment: @CodyMan: You are welcome. Please see my edited answer and select the answer which best suits you.

Comment: That's not working I have changed the data type to varchar

Comment: Where is the error either from the DB end or App end

Comment: it says string or binary data would be truncated

Comment: Check the inserted value especially varchar columns. Somewhere you are providing more than the limit. Lets say you declared as varchar(20) but you are giving 30 characters. I think you got my point

Comment: I have not exceeded the limit check here: prntscr.com/ad2j2i

Answer (score 2):

You define `cust_mobile` as `int`, but try to insert `03451119182`, which is clearly over the limit of `2147483647`.

Change to `bigint` or store as a VarChar (including the leading zero).

Answer (score 0):

You exceeded the limit of the `int` try with `bigint`

this value **3451119182**

see in this link the limits

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187745(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: yup! i didn't knew it.